# Metaio & Unity object tracking

Tags: unity-game-engine, metaio

I am adding an 3d object to marker,face tracking etc. no problem with that, but i also want to add the scene some 3d objects without changing position with the marker movement.

So an object changing position with the marker and an object position is not effected with the marker and i will going to implement some collision methods etc. I could not add an fixed position object and marker tracking object at the same time.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.